# Macbook Pro 2020 open with one hand

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently bought a Macbook Pro 2020 base model but I cannot open the lid with one hand. The opening is smooth no doubt but I have to use other hand to the base.

Is this uncommon?

Comment: This is common with all new laptops, especially the lighter/thinner kind (PCs too) As it gets used the hinge loosens a little, but in my experience it may not loosen enough to allow a *lift with one hand open.*

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal. The variation in the clutch and hinge strength is quite low. The variation in hand placement, position, size, strength, number of digits and bones in people’s hands vary widely.

The kids are designed more for staying open at an angle for years than always opening with the weight of the bottom.

Starting from the MacBook Air and especially the MacBook 12 the weight of the processor is almost never enough to lift only the lid with one finger. Gravity usually needs an assist until many years of wear and openings have happened. Same with the Pro, but those have a higher base to lid weight ratio and you can sometimes get some of them to open without jiggling.